# Passing pointers to structures into C functions from TCL using SWIG

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct, swig

I'm attempting to build a test framework in TCL that will allow me to perform scripted tests on a remote device over a TCP socket. There already exists a Visual Basic interface and with SWIG in Ubuntu I'm reusing the C functions that it calls to build a shared library that will work as an extension to TCL. I have had success at incorporating basic functions, such as opening/closing sockets, and basic read/writes to single memory addresses on the device using SWIG's typemaps.i to provide pointers (*OUTPUT) to the readAddress function to return address values to TCL.

The problem is that for this to be useful I am going to have to incorporate a large number of Remote Procedure Calls which pass complicated data types into (and back out of!) the device. As a proof of concept I'm attempting to get a relatively simple function working. This attempts to read default test parameters via an RPC; a pointer to a struct is provided for the function to use for the results: `rpc_testDefaults ( testDefaults_t *testDefaults )`.

The typedef for `testDefaults_t` is in testDefaults.h, which is in the style of the following:

```
// testDefaults.h
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t   customType_t;

typedef struct
{
    customType_t   varName1;    // Description
    uint32_t       varName2;    // Description

    // 13 more uint32_t elements

} testDefaults_t;

// Two more struct type definitions
```

testDefaults.c is along the lines of this:

```
// testDefaults.c
#include "testDefaults.h"

// #ifdefs to compile as 'client' OR 'server' (defaults to 'client')

rpc_testDefaults ( testDefaults_t, *testDefaults )
{
    // function
}
```

My SWIG interface file looks like this:

```
// rpcTest.i
%module rpcTest
%include <cpointer.i>
%include "testDefaults.h"
%pointer_functions(testDefaults_t, testDefaults);
//%apply int *OUTPUT {testDefaults_t, *testDefaults};

%{
    #include "testDefaults.h"
    extern int rpc_testDefaults ( testDefaults_t, *testDefaults )
}%

extern int rpc_testDefaults ( testDefaults_t, *testDefaults )
```

There are many other .c and header files in the same folder which support this function and the others which I mentioned I got working.

I run `swig -tcl -debug-typedef rpcTest.i` which gives me rpcTest_wrap.c, I can see that the testDefaults_t has been recognised as a type/scope as is has a section in the debug output (it's also included in the unnamed scope section: `testDefaults_t -> testDefaults_t`).

I run `gcc -fPIC -DCLIENT_FLAG -c *.c -I/usr/include/tcl8.5` and I get an error from a line in the SWIG output file: `rpcTest_wrap.c:1803:3: error: unknown type name 'testDefaults_t'` (plus a lot more errors derived from this). The line in question is the first line in this function:

```
static testDefaults_t *new_testDefaults() {
    return (testDefaults_t *)malloc(sizeof(testDefaults_t));
}
```

Which I believe is cpointers.i creating a function for TCL to 'create' a pointer to that struct.

I have a feeling this is something to do with gcc including files in the wrong order, but I'm at a loss as to what to do next. I've tried many combinations of defining the header in various places in the interface file and this is the combination that gives the least errors :). You can see my commented-out partial attempt at using typemaps instead of cpointers but I'm even more clueless with these, I managed it for a pointer to a single value but it didn't seem to be working for a struct with it's own type. It did compile without error though.

So is it possible to get what I'm trying to achieve working using cpointers.i? Any suggestions on how to overcome the compiler issue? Would I be better off learning how to use typemaps? Let me know where I can provide more detail if it would help, I may be leaving out crucial information as I've had to summarize and change all the names as this is company stuff.

Any help/criticism would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the rpcTest_wrap.c file I noticed that the include for testDefaults.h was right after the group of functions that were attempting to use it. I replaced "int" in the interface file with testDefaults_t (I think this is correct), ran SWIG, edited the output (dangerous I know!) so that the include happened just before these functions, and it compiles fine. I can load the shared library into TCL and run the new functions.

However, and this is perhaps a new question, [in TCL] using the new functions to create a pointer, feed it into rpc_testDefaults, and attempting to dereference the resulting pointer using testDefaults_value just returns another pointer. I realize that I can't just dereference a struct, but I have no idea how to dereference individual elements. Any tutorials I can find only refer to dereferencing non-structs (and none of these tutorials are for TCL). Something somewhere mentioned that there are similarities between structs and TK widgets so I'll have a look into this, but I'm still not sure is what I'm attempting to do even possible, and if it is is this the right way to do it.

Again, what I am attempting to do is in TCL, access individual elements of a struct which has been returned from (or fed into) a C function via a pointer.

UPDATE: I got this working in the end by using the functions SWIG generates which I discovered in the end of the wrapper file. `cpointer.i` wasn't needed at all. In TCL I first create a pointer using the new function new_testDefaults which returns a string with in the form of a TCL style pointer. I pass this pointer into rpc_testDefaults, which returns nothing as it was actually a void function. I can then access individual elements from the struct referenced by the above pointer by setting it as an argument to the elementName_get and elementName_set functions generated by SWIG. The next task is to get more complicated functions working, structs in structs etc, but now that I'm familiar with the methodology it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: As a further note, moving %pointer_function(... to the bottom of the interface file sorted out the gcc compiling issue.